# React Native - How to separate Card element

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am new to React Native and trying to figure out how to split a Card element. Everything else is working as expected - each individual item within the single card is clickable but I'd like to separate the two items into two separate cards that are clickable.

**Current Result**

[image]

**ItemComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Card, ListItem, Button, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class ItemComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Card containerStyle={{ padding: 10 }} >
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <SafeAreaView key={index}>
              <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate("Dashboard", { screen: "Dashboard" })}>
                  <ListItem
                    key={index}
                    title={item.name}
                    leftAvatar={{
                      source: require('../assets/mechanic.png')
                    }}
                    subtitle='Mechanic'
                    bottomDivider
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
          );
        })}
      </Card>

  );
 }
  }
   export default withNavigation(ItemComponent);
```

**FindMechanics.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import ItemComponent from '../components/ItemComponent';

export default class FindMechanics extends Component {
  state = {
    items: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    var query = firebase.database().ref("MechanicList").orderByKey();
    query.on('value', snapshot => {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let items = Object.values(data);
      this.setState({ items });
    });

  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <View style={styles.container}>    
        {this.state.items.length > 0 ? (
          <ItemComponent items={this.state.items} />
        ) : (
            <Text>No items</Text>
          )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  card: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '80%',
  }
});
```

**Expected Result**

[image]

Note how in the expected result the cards are separate or divided.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the FlatList for this. Here is the modified example from the [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/using-a-listview):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  SafeAreaView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import {Card} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Dan'},
            {key: 'Dominic'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <Card containerStyle={styles.card}>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text>{item.key}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Card>
          )}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 22,
  },
  card: {
    backgroundColor: '#2089dc',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks very much.